# Rust: joining thread fails with: cannot move out of dereference of `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, models::worker::Worker>`

Tags: rust

I am having a hard time figuring out how to sort out this issue.

So I have a class `ArcWorker` holding a shared reference to Worker (as you can remark below).

I wrote a function in `ArcWorker` called `join()` in which the line `self.internal.lock().unwrap().join();` fails with the following error:

> cannot move out of dereference of `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, models::worker::Worker>`

What I attempt through that line is to lock the mutex, unwrap and call the `join()` function from the Worker class.

As far as I understand, once that the lock function is called and it borrows a reference to self (&self), then I need some way to get to pass self by value to join (std::thread's join function requires passing self by value).

What can I do to make this work? Tried to find an answer to my question for hours but to no avail.

```
pub struct Worker {
  accounts: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Account>>>,
  thread_join_handle: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>
}

pub struct ArcWorker {
  internal: Arc<Mutex<Worker>>
}

impl ArcWorker {
  pub fn new(accounts: Vec<Arc<Mutex<Account>>>) -> ArcWorker {
    return ArcWorker {
      internal: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Worker {
        accounts: accounts,
        thread_join_handle: None
      }))
    }
  }

  pub fn spawn(&self) {
    let local_self_1 = self.internal.clone();
    
    self.internal.lock().unwrap().thread_join_handle = Some(thread::spawn(move || {
      println!("Spawn worker");
      local_self_1.lock().unwrap().perform_random_transactions();
    }));
  }

  pub fn join(&self) {
    self.internal.lock().unwrap().join();
  }
}

impl Worker {
  fn join(self) {
    if let Some(thread_join_handle) = self.thread_join_handle {
      thread_join_handle.join().expect("Couldn't join the associated threads.")
    }
  }

  fn perform_random_transactions(&self) {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Since you already hold `JoinHandle` in an `Option`, you can make `Worker::join()` take `&mut self` instead of `self` and change the `if let` to `if let  Some(thread_join_handle) = self.thread_join_handle.take()` (note the added [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take)). Then `ArcWorker::join()` should compile as-is.

Comment: Awesome, that was what I need. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already hold `JoinHandle` in an option, you can make `Worker::join()` take `&mut self` instead of `self` and change the `if let` condition to:

```
// note added `.take()`
if let Some(thread_join_handle) = self.thread_join_handle.take() {
```

[`Option::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) will move the handle out of the option and give you ownership over it, while leaving `None` in `self.thread_join_handle`. With this change `ArcWorker::join()` should compile as-is.